# Fill missing rows based on index number gaps, why does it work? - pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series, fill, gaps-in-data

So say i have a pandas series, as:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2],index=[0,3])
```

---

```
0    1
3    2
dtype: int64
```

And there's a gap between `0` and `3` in the index, so what i want is to add more rows to fill up the gaps to get the index of `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.

So desired output would look like:

```
0    1.0
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    2.0
dtype: float64
```

And i did:

```
print(s.reindex(range(s.index.min(),s.index.max()+1)))
```

And it worked!

But why?

I expected a result of:

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
dtype: float64
```

But it doesn't, and gives expected one!

(you know, i was ready to create a question about how to do this, but while ready to show an attempt, i solved it :D, so asked a question why did it work :-) , lol )

Comment: Which one is the output you are looking for? *'desired'* or *'expected'* ?

Comment: @Austin Desired is what i am looking for, and expected is the one i thought the code would give

Comment: @Austin So basically, asking why the code works.

Comment: i think you're conflating the behaviour of `reindex` with `reset_index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Intrinsic data alignment.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#intro-to-data-structures)  Basically, your source data is aligned with index 0 and 3.  When you use reindex, you are creating new rows 1, and 2 and reusing 0 and 3.

Watch what happens if you do:

```
s.reindex([0,0,3,3])
```

Output:

```
0    1
0    1
3    2
3    2
dtype: int64
```

Pandas automatically using index alignment.

Or

```
s.reindex([1,2,5,6])
```

Output:

```
1   NaN
2   NaN
5   NaN
6   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Wow, that's very useful, Note: first example is `reindex` instead of `indeX` right?

Comment: @U9-Forward Thank you.  Correct.

Comment: Okay, happy i caught the mistake :-)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simply because how [`reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) is implemented.

If you take a look at the example given in the documentation, executing `reindex()` only adds the missing index in the specified range with NaN value. It does not suppose to change the index of the available entry.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the info, you're right, that's the use of `reindex`!

Comment: Sorry, but only can accept one, so i can't do anything.

Comment: Yes, every time you are not sure about how something works, either look through the implementation in source code, or go to the documentation.